# SocketException when downloading any plugin related files for ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, socketexception

I am connecting to a Red Hat VM through Putty and a VCN. I am running an ElasticSearch cluster with one node. I am trying to install the marvel plugin with the following command

`./bin/plugin install --verbose marvel-agent`

which fails and produces

```
-> Installing marvel-agent...
Trying https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/release/org/elasticsearch/plugin/marvel-agent/2.3.3/marvel-agent-2.3.3.zip ...
ERROR: failed to download out of all possible locations..., use --verbose to get detailed information
```

I am new to ElasticSearch and there isn't very much help when googling this error. One thing I read was that this error occurs when the Elastic Search cluster can't connect to the network, but I don't see how to check this. Another thing I considered was the `network.host` setting

`network.host: 127.0.0.1`

I am not able to download license either.

can someone give some advice?

Comment: Have you tried `curl`ing the zip?

Comment: if you mean downloading the curl with zip, I just tried that and got network is unreachable

Comment: Is it possible you have a Proxy/Firewall in the way? This is not an elasticsearch issue if you can't curl it, it means you don't have internet accss from the vm.

Comment: but I am able to browse the internet within the VM

Comment: you were right, proxy settings